# WSL gets different PATHs depending on how I invoke scripts

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Consider the following PowerShell session:

```
~ λ wsl echo '$PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:... #redacted for brevity
~ λ wsl
taschan@georg:/mnt/c/Users/Tomas Aschan$ echo $PATH
/home/taschan/bin:/home/taschan/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:...
```

As you can see, the `$PATH` variable has different contents depending on whether I start an interactive WSL session (`wsl`) or run a script directly (`wsl echo '$PATH'`).

I'm not surprised that `~/bin` is in my path in the interactive session; I have a line in my `.bashrc` that sets it so.

But why is this not run when executing a script using `wsl <thescript>`? Can I somehow tell `wsl` that I want my profile settings available also when running a script directly?

Answer (score 0):

A process inherits its environment from its parent.
This means that the environment will differ when the process is started from
the Command Prompt or from WSL.
In addition, when running a script directly this doesn't start a login shell,
so not all initialization scripts are executed, and specifically not `.bashrc`.

I believe that code in `~/.bash_profile` would be executed in both cases,
so perhaps that's a safer place for it.
When I last researched the subject, bash only loaded the first one in
`.bash_profile`, `.bash_login` or `.profile`,
so be careful with the initialization script you use.

You could also use `bash.exe -ic command` instead of `wsl.exe` for
invoking an interactive shell when executing the command.
The caveat is that `bash.exe` is currently said to be deprecated, so this seems less
than ideal, although it still works and will continue to work for some time.